# ManyToMany can't save Task on inverse side

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

Owning side:

```
/**
 * Task
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="task")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TaskRepository")
 */
class Task
{
//...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="tasks", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="categories_tasks")
     */
    private $categories;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...

    public function setCategories(Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $categories;
    }
```

Inverse side:

```
/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{


    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="categories", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="categories_tasks")
     */
    private $tasks;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tasks = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    //...

    public function getTasks()
    {
        return $this->tasks;
    }

    public function setTasks(Task $task)
    {
        $this->tasks = $task;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function addTask(Task $task)
    {
        if (!$this->tasks->contains($task)) {
            $this->tasks->add($task);
            $task->setCategories($this);

            return $this;
        }
    }

    public function removeTask (Task $task)
    {
        if ($this->tasks->contains($task)) {
            $this->tasks->remove($task);
            $task->removeCategory($this);
        }
    }
}
```

I can save Categories with Task. I can't save Tasks with Category. I studied carefully [Association Mapping from Doctrine's website](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) but with no good result. I spent last hour reading similar cases from stack and of course I tried adding some codes but still no working solution. What I miss?

I do the thing partially by code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($category);

$tasks = $category->getTasks();
foreach($tasks as $t)
{
    $t->setCategories($category);
    $em->persist($t);
}
$em->flush();
```

but it's not perfect and I don't want to go this way because I'm quite sure that I do some easy mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these methode in your entities:

```
/**
 * Add category
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $category
 *
 * @return Task
 */
public function addCategory(Category $category)
{
    $this->categories[] = $competition;
    $category->addTask($this);

    return $this;
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Add task
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Task $task
 *
 * @return Category
 */
public function addTask(Task $task)
{
    $this->tasks[] = $task;
    $task->addCategory($this);

    return $this;
}
```

and then,

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$task->addCategory($category)
$em->persist($task);
$em->flush();
```

or

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$category->addTask($task)
$em->persist($category);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-6' for key 'PRIMARY' :( I do simple movie: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oh6060evshzdu9/symfony%20many%20to%20many%20problem.mp4?dl=0 I had to remove line $category->addTask($task) because it causes 500

Comment: So the problem is with trying persist Tasks with already are connected with current Category.

Comment: Dont do both methods on each sides, only one is needed on the inverse side to call setters.

Answer (score 0):

I would say almost like @Benoit, but actually, I don't think you need to persist the entities added that way (and if it was needed, it would make more sense to persist the newly created entity).

So

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$task->addCategory($category)
$em->persist($task);
$em->flush();
```

Becomes

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$task->addCategory($category);
$em->flush();
```

Edit: assuming entity manager has handle on the $task object

Edit2 (from comment): Since your category already exists and is fetched, remove the persist($category) from your code.

Comment: That's also work but here is the same problem as in @Benoit solution: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-2' for key 'PRIMARY'. Here I show exactly: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oh6060evshzdu9/symfony%20many%20to%20many%20problem.mp4?dl=0

Comment: You action seems to be an edit feature, I suppose then that your category already exists. You can then remove all the persist($category) from the code of your action.
The problem comes from the fact you're trying to create an entity that already exists.
Just do the add(), then flush().

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution (similar to previous variants)

App\Entity\Task

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Task
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="tasks", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $categories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function addCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $this->categories[] = $category;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if ($this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $this->categories->removeElement($category);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

App\Entity\Category

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Task", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $tasks;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tasks = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTasks(): Collection
    {
        return $this->tasks;
    }

    public function addTask(Task $task): self
    {
        if (!$this->tasks->contains($task)) {
            $this->tasks[] = $task;
            $task->addCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTask(Task $task): self
    {
        if ($this->tasks->contains($task)) {
            $this->tasks->removeElement($task);
            $task->removeCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Saving process:

```
// ...
$task->addCategory($category);
$em->persist($task);
$em->flush();
```

or

```
// ...
$category->addTask($task);
$em->persist($category);
$em->flush();
```

Hope helps

PS in your editAction you can try saving in this way:

```
if ($editingForm->isSubmited() && $editingForm->isSubmited()) {
    $em->persist($category);
    $em->flush();
}
```